# Dendogram not coming properly

Tags: r, hierarchical-clustering

I am not able to understand this dendo[Heirarchial Clustering](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ntHO9.png)gram in R. Kindly help me with this

Comment: Can anyone help me in interpreting this dendogram

Comment: Can you please provide your code for generating this dendrogram? And any details you can provide would also help a lot. For example, what data are you trying to cluster? what linkage did you use? Without a complete example, it is difficult to help you.

Comment: Please read the info about [how to ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and how to give a [reproducible example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example/5963610). This will make it much easier for others to help you.

Comment: make the figure bigger, text smaller, use fewer features, etc. all the text is running together making it unreadable

Answer (score 0):

Have a look here: http://www.sthda.com/english/wiki/beautiful-dendrogram-visualizations-in-r-5-must-known-methods-unsupervised-machine-learning

For instance, using cex argument to change the size of the font, e.g.

```
plot(hc, cex = 0.6)
```

Or try other ways of visualising like as an unrooted phylogenetic tree:

```
library("ape")
plot(as.phylo(hc), type = "unrooted", cex = 0.6, no.margin = TRUE)
```